# Jekyll and liquid - Show related posts by amount of equal tags >= 2

Tags: tags, jekyll, liquid

i'd like to add a bar called "related posts" at the bottom of each post and the criteria for posts to be related and to appear there should be that there is an *amount of minimum 2 equal tags in both posts*.

My approach so far:

```
{% for tag in page.tags %}

    {% assign currentTag = tag | first %}


    {% for post in site.posts | limit:3 %}
        {% if post.tags contains currentTag | plus:1 %}

        <div> 
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">
            <img src="{{site.baseurl}}/asset/img/{{ post.img-thumb }}">
        </a>
        <h5> {{ post.title }}</h5>
        </div>


        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: btw: does anyone know what the criteria is for the site variable site.related_posts ?
http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code does the trick :

```
<div class="relatedPosts">

  <h3>Related post</h3>

  {% comment %}---> the maximum number of related to posts 
                    to be printed {% endcomment %}
  {% assign maxRelated = 5 %}

  {% comment %}---> the minimum number of common tags 
                    to have for a post to be considered 
                    as a related post {% endcomment %}
  {% assign minCommonTags =  3 %}

  {% assign maxRelatedCounter = 0 %}

  {% for post in site.posts %}

    {% assign sameTagCount = 0 %}
    {% assign commonTags = '' %}

    {% for tag in post.tags %}
      {% comment %}---> Only compare if post is 
                        not same as current page {% endcomment %}
      {% if post.url != page.url %}
        {% if page.tags contains tag %}
          {% assign sameTagCount = sameTagCount | plus: 1 %}
          {% capture tagmarkup %} <span class="label label-default">{{ tag }}</span> {% endcapture %}
          {% assign commonTags = commonTags | append: tagmarkup %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if sameTagCount >= minCommonTags %}
      <div>
      <h5><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}{{ commonTags }}</a></h5>
      </div>
      {% assign maxRelatedCounter = maxRelatedCounter | plus: 1 %}
      {% if maxRelatedCounter >= maxRelated %}
        {% break %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}

</div>
```

**Edit** : Added 'configuration' for `maxRelated` and `minCommonTags`, plus a test to avoid putting a post in is own related post list.